# Why do I have to click to activate plugins with Flash player for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, flash, flowplayer

want to play video on android TV,  I use flowpplayer 3, Adobe Flash Player for Android is version 11.1.115.81 and  browser is firefox.

My code:

```
<script src="flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body >
    <a href="flowplayer-700.flv"  style="display:block; width:425px; height:300px;" id="player"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.swf");
            $('.play').click(function(){
                $f('player').play();
            });
            $('.stop').click(function(){
                $f('player').stop();
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

When play it on Android, it ask to click to activate, but on Windows it does not.

I need play automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flashfox works.My code has no peoblem.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma   Answer is using Flashfox ...... `Flashfox works`, you didn't see it , It's your fault.

Comment: @Yvette If the question changes to  "how to make flowplayer automaticlly playe a swf on android?", firefox  can't make it, but flashfox can. 
Does this bring value here?